# If $A\cap B = \emptyset$, prove that: $B\cap A'= B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A\cap B = \emptyset$, prove that: $B\cap A'= B$.

My Attempt:
Let $x$ be an element of $B\cap A'$.
$$x\in B\cap A' \implies x\in B\text { and }\space x\in A'$$
$$\implies x\in B\text{ and }\space x\notin A$$

How do I proceed further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue from your approach, you can conclude that $x \in B$, hence $B \cap A' \subseteq B$

Now you have to prove the other direction.

Alternative approach:

$$B = (B \cap A') \cup (B \cap A)=( B \cap A') \cup \emptyset = (B \cap A')$$

Answer (score 1):

$x\in B\cap A'\Rightarrow x\in B$, then $B\cap A'\subset B$

Let $\Omega$ is universal set.

$x\in B=B\cap \Omega=B\cap (A\cup A')=(B\cap A)\cup (B\cap A')\Rightarrow x\in B\cap A\space \text{or}\space x\in B\cap A'$. But since $B\cap A=A\cap B=\phi$, there is no such $x\in B$ such that $x\in A\cap B$. Thus $x\in B\cap A'$. Then $B\subset B\cap A'$.

Hence $B\cap A'=B\space\space\space\blacksquare$