# If $A\cap B = \emptyset$, prove that: $A\cup B'=B'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A\cap B = \emptyset$, prove that: $A\cup B'=B'$

My Attempt:
Let $x$ be an element of $A\cup B'$. Then
$$x\in A\cup B' \implies x\in A  \ \textrm {or} \  x \in B'$$
$$\implies x\in B'$$
So, $A\cup B' \subset B'$.

Again, Let $x$ be an element of $B'$
$$x\in B' \implies x\in U \ \textrm{and} \  x\notin B$$
where $U$ is the universal set.

How do I proceed?

Comment: The converse is easy, see the that $ A \subset A \cup B$

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach:

From your [Previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2374288/306553), you have proven that if $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then we have $B \cap A' = B$

From De Morgan's law, $$B'=(B \cap A')'=B' \cup A$$

Answer (score 1):

If  you have $A\cap B=\emptyset$ then this implies that $A\subseteq B'$, so the conclution follow.

Answer (score 0):

The first half needs  work. You say: $x \in A$ or $x \in B'$, therefore $x\in B'$. That goes a bit quick. Sure, if $x \in B'$ then $x \in B'$, but what if $x \in A$?  You still need to show that that also means that $x \in B'$ by using $A \cap B = \emptyset$.  Also, once you have shown this, you have that $A \cup B' \color{red} \subseteq B'$

The second half is actually the easy half. If $x \in B'$, then you certainly have that $x \in A$ or $x \in B'$, and hence $B' \subseteq A \cup B'$

Another approach is to do this purely algebraically:

$$B'= B' \cup \emptyset = B' \cup (A \cap B)= (B' \cup A) \cap (B \cup B') = (A \cup B') \cap U = A \cup B'$$

Answer (score 0):

1) Prove $A\cap B=\emptyset \implies A\subset B'$

2) prove $A\subset C \implies A\cup C=C $.

1) is easy.  If $x\in A $ then $x\in B $ would mean $x\in A\cap B $ which is impossible so $x\in A\implies x\in B'$.

2) is trivial.  $x\in A \cup C$ means $x\in A\subset C$ or $x\in C $.  Either way, $x\in C $ so $C\subset A\cup C\subset C $.